# How to fetch search data from databse in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here in my code I take a div `TextBoxContainer`. Now I want that when I click on `DynamicTextBox` in script `inputbox`, it displays search values, which are already in the database. I have tried already autocomplete for that but it doesn't work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> 
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function() {
        var div = $("<div />");
        div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
        $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);

      });
       $( "#DynamicTextBox" ).autocomplete({
          source: 'search1.php'

      });

      $("#btnGet").bind("click", function() {
        var values = 
          $.map($("input[name=DynamicTextBox]"), function(el) {
            return el.value
          }).join(",\n");
        $("#anotherTextbox").val(values);
      });
      $("#btnGet").bind("click", function() {
        var values = 
          $.map($("input[name=DynamicTextBox1]"), function(el) {
            return el.value
          }).join(",\n");
        $("#anotherTextbox1").val(values);
      });
      $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
        $(this).closest("div").remove();
      });

    });

    function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
      return '<input name = "DynamicTextBox" style="width:280px;margin-left:10px;" id="DynamicTextBox" class="skills" type="text" value = "' + value + '" />&nbsp;' + '<input style="width:280px;" name = "DynamicTextBox1" type="text" value = "' + value + '" />&nbsp;' +
        '<span type="button"  class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>'
    }
    </script>

<html>
 <div id="TextBoxContainer"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: please try to simple ajax function why are you do that complex method

Comment: i dont know how to do this..plz suggest..

Comment: please try in google to search with ajax in php

Comment: post your code here fully.